# Formatting a table

Tags: excel

Say I have a table in Excel of two columns and the first column only contains integers from 1 to N. I want to format the second column into a table of N columns so that each value would be in a specific column - that is, the number of this column would be the integer, which corresponded to this value in the first table. That's what I mean:

First table

2 | 2.56
3 | 3.12
5 | 5.55
1 | 8.12
1 | 1.00
2 | 9.30

Second table (consists of 5 columns)

8.12 | 9.30 | 3.12 | - | 5.55
1.00 | 2.56

Can I do that automatically?

Comment: Which language are you thinking about doing this in?

Comment: I believe there're standard ways to do that in Excel. I would have no problems writing a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head your first column 'Col' and your second column 'Number'. Make a third column with a header of 'Row'. In the third column, put

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

And fill down as far as your data goes.

Make a pivot table from the data. Put 'Col' in Column Labels, 'Row' in Row Labels, and 'Sum of Number' in Values.

[image]

Comment: Specifications? Who needs 'em! Nice catch.